# getting The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null in knexjs while executing migrate

Tags: node.js, next.js, knex.js

I am using knex.js with next.js 13 and I wanted to use migrate command to create new table but when I am trying to execute this command .
`npx knex migrate:make create_test_table`

I am getting this error.

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:167:9)
    at D:\withdraw\withdraw\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\MigrationGenerator.js:79:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MigrationGenerator._absoluteConfigDirs (D:\withdraw\withdraw\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\MigrationGenerator.js:73:24)
    at MigrationGenerator._ensureFolder (D:\withdraw\withdraw\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\MigrationGenerator.js:28:23)
    at MigrationGenerator.make (D:\withdraw\withdraw\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\MigrationGenerator.js:20:16)
    at Migrator.make (D:\withdraw\withdraw\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\Migrator.js:315:27)
    at Command.<anonymous> (D:\withdraw\withdraw\node_modules\knex\bin\cli.js:231:12)
```

my folder structure is like this.
in root directory

```
/config
  /database
    /migrations
    /seed
    Knexfile.ts
```

my Knexfile.ts

```
import { Knex } from "knex";

interface KnexConfig {
  development: {
    client: "pg";
    connection: {
      host: string;
      user: string;
      password: string;
      database: string;
    };
    migrations: {
      directory: string;
    };
    seeds: {
      directory: string;
    };
  };
}

const config: KnexConfig = {
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: "localhost",
      user: "postgres",
      password: "password",
      database: "postgres",
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./database/migrations",
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: "./database/seed",
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

scripts in page.json

```
    "migrate": "knex --knexfile ./config/knexfile.ts migrate:latest",
    "seed": "knex --knexfile ./config/knexfile.ts seed:run"
```

it would be very helpful if someone could help me regarding this error and how to fix this.
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `directory` value is null in [MigrationGenerator.js](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/bbbe4d4637b3838e4a297a457460cd2c76a700d5/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js#L79).
To resolve this also by passing `directory` in command like

```bash
knex migrate:make --migrations-directory migration-folder create-this-table
```